# Apigee API Console for the Stack Exchange API

Tags: app, api

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

### About

Apigee API Consoles make it easier to learn, explore and test APIs by letting you browse all methods, send and view request/response pairs and share what you are seeing with others.

We just added support for the Stack Exchange API and hope you will take a look and let us know anything we're missing, feedback, etc. We also added a few other "geeky" APIs for your holiday hacking you should check out - Github, Face.com, Google Prediction and others :) All APIs we support can be found on http://apigee.com/providers

#### License

All Apigee Consoles are free to use and to create!

#### Download

https://apigee.com/console/stackexchange

#### Platform

Should support most browsers though we have seen some small issues with IE - if you see any browser compatibility issues, let us know!

### Contact

API Consoles are made by the team at Apigee. You can contact us at console@apigee.com, here or on Twitter (@apigee), or follow us on Github.

### Code

The Console is driven by a WADL document. You can find our WADL library on Github.

Comment: @Shanley - Are you going to update the Apigee API Console for the recently released [Stack Exchange API v2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), which specifically includes [optional authentication via OAuth 2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) for a respectively increased user experience as well?